# Angularjs orderBy is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have modified the example given in the angularjs docs. I put zero for all age fields in that example and when I click on the age sorting button the list is getting sorted (don't know on which parameter basis the list is getting sorted) although all the age fields are zero and should not be sorted.

> Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/85dmPRFu6IPhHnTkXqgU?p=preview

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <pre>Sort by = {{propertyName}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
      <hr />
      <button ng-click="propertyName = null; reverse = false">Set to unsorted</button>
      <hr />
      <table class="friends">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <button ng-click="sortBy('name')">Name</button>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <button ng-click="sortBy('phone')">Phone Number</button>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <button ng-click="sortBy('age')">Age</button>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
            <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var friends = [
      {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 0},
      {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 0},
      {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 0},
      {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 0},
      {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 0}
    ];

    $scope.propertyName = 'age';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.friends = friends;

    $scope.sortBy = function(propertyName) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
    };
  }
```

Comment: All the age fields are 0 So it will sort in the order of array given. And reverse will be the reverse order of given array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood angularjs uses [this function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6a3374968680ccd809b62ba22b834389ebba99bc/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js#L594):

```
function doComparison(v1, v2) {
  for (var i = 0, ii = predicates.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var result = compare(v1.predicateValues[i], v2.predicateValues[i]);
    if (result) {
      return result * predicates[i].descending * descending;
    }
  }

  return compare(v1.tieBreaker, v2.tieBreaker) * descending;
}
```

Since your `v1` and `v2` are always the same, `compare(v1.tieBreaker, v2.tieBreaker)` will always return the same value `-1` (since `v1.value` is equal to `v2.value` a tieBreaker is used), whereas `descending` variable will be either `-1` or `1` depending on sort order. This is what makes angular change order.

If you wouldn't use `sortOrder` in this filter:

```
friend in friends | orderBy:propertyName:reverse
```

or didn't change is on each click here:

```
$scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
```

the order wouldn't change.

Comment: So is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Since you can't change anything in the angular.js sources, you have to either not change `reverse` if `propertyName ` of all values of an array are equal, or provide your custom `sortBy` comparator

Comment: Thank you. I've added a check before changing `$scope.reverse` value.

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli, you're welcome, you can accept my answer then

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason behind your output is that when you click on age filter, the data will not be sorted anymore. It is showing your `$scope.friends` in the exact order that is saved declared in the controller.

Comment: It is showing the exact order only on first click. The order is changing after first click.

Answer (score 0):

As @Maximus suggested, I've added a check before toggling the value of `$scope.reverse` to true or false.

```
$scope.sortBy = function(propertyName) {

      $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
     // check all the values of propertyName i.e. age in the array
     for (var i=0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        // toggle $scope.reverse only when the values are not same (zero in my case)
        if (friends[i].age !== 0) {
            $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        }
    }
    };
```

> https://plnkr.co/edit/vMira2iF94yuOqJw3gA7?p=preview

Comment: can you post it as a separate question? You might get more input on that problem than just from me. I've answered the question why that happens. I may not have enough knowledge to suggest how to fix it.

Comment: you can link the question here when you ask it